# Show selected xml data in label

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml file with users with different types of tasks.

```
<Users>
  <Instructor>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <Surname>C</Surname>
    <Rank>r1</Rank>
  </Instructor>
  <Instructor>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Jim</Name>
    <Surname>A</Surname>
    <Rank>r1</Rank>
  </Instructor>
  <Pilot>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Tim</Name>
    <Surname>T</Surname>
    <Rank>r2</Rank>
  </Pilot>
</Users>
```

I am passing the ids of the users who are in the instructor task to the combobox with the code below.

```
void InsGetCombo()
{
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds.ReadXml(path);
     DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Instructor"];
     comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
     comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID";
}
```

What I want to do here is to show the id, name, surname and rank values on label1, of the record with the id value I selected in the combobox.

I tried to get just Name with string id not with selectedIndex but could not get the value.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        string id = "2";
        label1.Text = doc.SelectSingleNode($"/Users/Instructor[ID='{id}']").Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I showed you the right direction: to use a typed collection of model classes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75222229/5045688

Comment: Next, just use [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/data/overview?view=netdesktop-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

To select the node whose ID element is in the `id` variable, you could use an XPath expression something like this: `$"/Users/Instructor/ID[text()='{id}']/parent::*”`. Since what you ultimately want is the value of that element’s Name element, you might use this instead, `$"/Users/Instructor/ID[text()='{id}']/parent::*/Name/text()”`. If you want need the value of other elements, remember that `ID`, `Name`, `Surname` and `Rank` are *child elements* of the `Instructor` node, not *attributes* of it.

Answer (score -1):

Use [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/data/overview?view=netdesktop-7.0).

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ComboBox comboBox;
        Label nameLabel;
        Label surnameLabel;
        Label rankLabel;

        DataSet dataSet;
        DataTable instructorsDataTable;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            comboBox = new ComboBox { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Left };
            nameLabel = new Label { Parent = this, Left = 150 };
            surnameLabel = new Label { Parent = this, Left = 150, Top = 30 };
            rankLabel = new Label { Parent = this, Left = 150, Top = 60 };

            this.Load += Form1_Load;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml("test.xml");

            instructorsDataTable = dataSet.Tables["Instructor"];

            comboBox.DisplayMember = "Id";
            comboBox.DataSource = instructorsDataTable;

            nameLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", instructorsDataTable, "Name");
            surnameLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", instructorsDataTable, "Surname");
            rankLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", instructorsDataTable, "Rank");
        }
    }
}
```